# line-height is not working in phonegap developer app

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm using Onsen ui to build a phonegap app. There are default styles for everything. Like toolbar navigation etc. Toolbar has three components left center and right. Toolbar's height is 44px by default so is the line-height. Everything is working fine in a desktop/mobile browser. But, not in phonegap developer app. I noticed that the problem is related to the line-height. So I applied top padding, It's working but only on high resolution devices.
Here is the code I'm using.
**HTML**

```
<ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center text-center">PHPTRAVELS</div>
      <div class="right">
        <ons-toolbar-button>
            <ons-icon icon="refresh" size="30px" spin="{{isFetching}}" fixed-width="true"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
    </ons-toolbar>
```

**CSS**

```
    .navigation-bar__left {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 27%;
  text-align: left;

}

.navigation-bar__right {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 27%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}

.navigation-bar__title {
  line-height: 44px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #dbd8d8;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

.navigation-bar__center {
  width: 46%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #dbd8d8;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```